# Как сделать oauth2 авторизацию?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Получается у меня есть кнопка, и вызов окна этого с js осуществляется
https://lootdog.me/oauth/ - то что у меня есть, у меня такое окно.
Вот как сделать чтоб вот так было? https://prnt.sc/tknz83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно использовать модуль passport
более подробно с библиотекой можно ознакомиться по ссылке: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/

Для этого так же потребуется зарегистрировать свое приложение в сервисе, который предоставляет возможность залогиниться(vk, facebook, google), возможность тестирования на localhost точно предоставляет google